# How to skip row when for loop is executing and row is empty

Tags: java, selenium

I have 2 excel sheets, I am comparing cell values using the `testNg` Assertion. Following are the values in sheet1 and sheet2, after `david`, I have an empty row in both the sheets, my script is failing since row 3 is blank and it's not going to row 4?

```
Sheet1  Sheet2

sachin  sachin
david   david

winter  winter
```

I have written following code:-

```
int rowCount = xlib.getRowCount("Sheet1");

for (int i = 0; i<=rowCount;i++)
{
    String compair1= xlib.getExcelData("Sheet1", i, 0);
    System.out.println(compair1);
    String compair2=xlib.getExcelData("Sheet2", i, 0); 
    System.out.println(compair2);
    Assert.assertEquals(compair1, compair2);
    System.out.println("compared successfully");
}
```

Need correct code, it should skip the 3rd row since it has blank value and move to 4th row and compare and pass the script.

Comment: Add check for the value compair1 or compair2 to be null, and if so don't Assert.

Comment: You could just clean up your data... or grab all data and filter out empties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `continue` statement.

```java
int rowCount = xlib.getRowCount("Sheet1");

for (int i = 0; i<=rowCount;i++)
{
    try {
        String compair1= xlib.getExcelData("Sheet1", i, 0);
        System.out.println(compair1);
        String compair2=xlib.getExcelData("Sheet2", i, 0); 
        System.out.println(compair2);
        Assert.assertEquals(compair1, compair2);
        System.out.println("compared successfully");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that helped !!! But I have another challenge, I am having some rows with date format (mm-dd-yyyy) , it is failing to read that entry , it is saying text cell value as numeric, is there any way, I can read the date format and compare both the sheets or should I need to change the date format in the excel itself?

Comment: That counts as another question and hence should be separate from this one. Please ask a separate question regarding this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the loop from i to i<=2.
Following that loop, do another loop from i=4 to i <=rowCount.

Comment: this is one example, but actually I have to 50 rows, some are blank in the middle, I cannot use many loops instead can I get something if statement stating if row is blank skip and move to next row like that?

Comment: Oh in that case, TheChubbyPanda's answer should be what you're looking for.